LXML automatically converts Windows newlines
I am trying to parse an XML string that contains Windows newlines (the CR, LF pair):
from lxml.etree import XML

root = XML('<root>_\r\n_\n_</root>')
print(
    [ord(char) for char in root.text],
)

but the resulting text surprisingly contains only Linux newlines (LF character):
[95, 10, 95, 10, 95]

Is it a feature, documented somewhere? Is it possible to change its behavior to access the unmodified text?
I am using (currently the newest) LXML 5.2.2.

The linked question is not relevant to my question - it talks about software changes between Fedora 17 and 18, while this behavior, as mentioned here in the comments, turns out to be defined in the XML standard. Also, the answer does not answer my question - it recommends to replace the manually added newlines with a triple quoted string.

It got very quickly closed as a duplicate but I fail to see how the linked answer answers my question. The recommendation there is to replace manually added newlines with a triple-quoted string.

It is XML parsing rules https://www.w3.org/TR/xml/#sec-line-ends that require "To simplify the tasks of applications, the XML processor must behave as if it normalized all line breaks in external parsed entities (including the document entity) on input, before parsing, by translating both the two-character sequence #xD #xA and any #xD that is not followed by #xA to a single #xA character."

@MartinHonnen Thank you! I would accept that as an answer.
